# Need help understanding the math in ISO 22514-6:2013 Annex A

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Word for word out of the "ISO 22514-6:2013 Annex A" standard:

A.2 Motivation for the definitions of multivariate capability

Consider first the ${C_p}$ index in the one-dimensional case. The tolerance interval is the interval [L, U]. Let X ~ *N*(${  \mu , \sigma ^{2} }$) with ${\mu}$=(U+L)/2, i.e. the distribution is centered on the midpoint of the tolerance interval. The probability that a process value lies inside the tolerance interval

$${ P= P_ {N((U+L)/2, \sigma ^{2} )}(L \lt X \lt U) =P_ {N((U+L)/2, \sigma ^{2} )}\left(L- \frac{L+U}{2} \lt X- \frac{L+U}{2} \lt U- \frac{L+U}{2} \right)}$$

$${  =P_ {N((U+L)/2, \sigma ^{2} )}\left(\frac{L-U}{2 \sigma } \lt \frac{X- \frac{L+U}{2}}{ \sigma } \lt \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)= \Phi \left( \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)- \Phi \left( - \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)}$$

$${= \Phi \left( \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)- \left[ 1-\Phi \left( - \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)\right]=2\Phi \left( \frac{U-L}{2 \sigma } \right)-1=2 \Phi (3 C_p )-1}$$

It follows that

$${ \frac{1}{3} \Phi ^{-1} \left( \frac{P+1}{2} \right)}$$

where *P* is the probability that a process value lies inside the tolerance interval for a normal distribution centred on the midpoint of the tolerance interval and with variance ${\sigma^2}$.

I am not very familiar with this kind of math. I have taken classes in: Calculas 1 and 2 and Multivariate Calculus and Differential Equations. Although it has been a few years (10?) and if I did learn this stuff? I am a little rusty...

I understand Cp and Cpk rather well. I understand the terminology [L, U] to be the upper and lower specification usually referred to as USL and LSL when calculating Cp. In other words if you have a hole that is supposed to be 10 with a +/- 0.2 spec. Then the USL = 10.2 and LSL = 9.8

Also, I understand the next sentence to be "X behaves according to a Normal distribution with mean (${\mu}$) and variance (${\sigma^{2}}$)." I also understand the next sentence (U+L)/2. Again, using the example I used above of a hole that is supposed to be 10 with a +/- 0.2 spec. Your target is (USL - LSL) / 2 = (10.2 - 9.8) / 2 = 10. In other words, your target is 10. So it is simply saying your average hole size is the same as your target hole size.

After this... I quickly get lost... So... I gather that "P" is "Probability" and it is saying something about the probability with ${\mu}$=(U+L)/2 and variance = ${\sigma^{2}}$.

Then I gather that (L<X<U) means "the probability that X is between the upper and lower spec.

Then effectively the next step is ${(L- \mu )<(X- \mu )<(U- \mu)}$ but instead of ${\mu}$ they are using (U+L)/2. This is understandable since they said ${\mu}$=(U+L)/2 but what is the meaning of this step? I don't understand why they are doing this? Then in the next step ${\sigma}$ shows up in the denominator for some reason? Why? How? Then in the next step ${\Phi}$ shows up? Why? How? I have been digging and I have gathered that ${\Phi}$ is commonly used to represent "the standard normal CDF." I found several websites that have gotten me to this level of understanding. This link has a brief explanation related to  ${\Phi}$ that I think might be very helpful... But I also struggle to follow...

https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_2_3_normal.php

but at this point I am still struggling to connect the dots... Any help would be appreciated... I basically would like to understand how they are getting to the final calculation for Cp.

Comment: 1) Why this step - ${(L- \mu )<(X- \mu )<(U- \mu)}$? To make the mean 0.
2) Why $\sigma$ in the denominator? To make variance 1. 
3) Why use $\Phi$. Many real world problems are modelled by the normal distribution. Normal distributions are typically converted to "standard form", ie mean 0 variance 1, so that one can directly use pre-computed tables to read off the probabilities. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

The idea is that they have a function, $\Phi$, which computes the probability of a standard normal variable falling below a stated value. So, the entire computation is transforming the random variable that you start with, which they assume to be Gaussian with a mean, $\mu$, and a standard deviation, $\sigma$, to a standard gaussian which has a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

Really all this means is that they take a range for your starting Gaussian distribution $(a,b)$ and compute the equivalent range in a standard Gaussian $(\tilde{a}, \tilde{b})$. The standard practice then, is to compute $\Phi(\tilde{b}) - \Phi(\tilde{a})$ to get the probability of $x \in (a,b)$.

They use an equivalent expression for $\Phi(\tilde{b}) - \Phi(\tilde{a})$, namely $\Phi(\tilde{b}) - (1 - \Phi(-\tilde{a}))$, which works because the standard Gaussian is symmetric.

Then they rearrange the identity, and apply the inverse CDF, $\Phi^{-1}$, to isolate their defintion of $C_p$.

Please let me know if you need me to write this out more explicitly, and I'd be happy to.